# Angular Observale doesnt get the latest data from server after interval

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

Angular observable doesnt refresh/get latest data from database. It returns same data again and again after interval. I m manually changing data in database to check whether it works but doesnt update the values in angular observable **OrderTrackingList$** as well as in **orderTrackingList**. Not sure what I m doing wrong. Thanks for help

```
private refreshInterval$: Observable<any> = timer(0, 2000)
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.killTrigger),

      switchMap(() => this.fetchDataOrderTrackingMapDriverData$),

      catchError(error => of('Error'))
    );

this.OrderTrackingList$ = this.refreshInterval$;
    this.orderTrackingSubscription = this.OrderTrackingList$.subscribe(orderTrackingList => {

      console.log('Drivers Status ' + orderTrackingList.status[0].driver_status);
      console.log('Drivers List Length ' + orderTrackingList.status.length);

    });
```

Comment: show us the fetchDataOrderTrackingMapDriverData$ code

Comment: @noririco   **private fetchDataOrderTrackingMapDriverData$: Observable<any> = this._dataService.getDriverList('DRIVERTRACKING');**

Comment: @noririco above is the fetchDataOrderTrackingMapDriverData$ code

Comment: Api url is not triggering every 2sec